Symmetry preserving quadratic forms
Let $A$ and $S$ be conformable matrices with $S$ symmetric. One frequent annoyance is that the product:
$$
\tilde{S} = ASA^\intercal
$$
has antisymmetric components due to rounding. Is there a simple scheme for multiplying these matrices that preserves symmetry numerically? Note:

Multiplication and addition can be assumed to still possess commutativity
Both lose associativity

Obviously, you can perform a matrix decomposition on $S$ to achieve this. For example, an eigenvalue decomposition quickly leads to:
$$
S = A\left(\sum_{k=1}^d \lambda_i v_iv_i^\intercal\right)A^\mathsf{T} = \sum_{k=0}^d \lambda_i (Av_i)(Av_i)^\intercal = \sum_{k=1}^d \lambda_i u_iu_i^\intercal = \sum_{k=1}^d \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_i (u_{1}u_1) & \cdots & \lambda_i(u_{1}u_d)\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \lambda_i(u_{d}u_1) & \cdots & \lambda_i(u_{n}u_n) \end{bmatrix}
$$
and from here, it is easy to observe that the eigenvalue decomposition achieves this. However, needing to form the decomposition first is unappealing; it feels like there should be a way to accomplish this without first decomposing.

Post-hoc averaging the result with its transpose?

This is probably the most common way to do it, but it's a practical suggestion which is very brute force. I just end up with products of this form in practice over and over again, and I just want to write code one time that resolves this problem so I never have to think about it again.
I'm sure others encounter it frequently too so it feels like there should be a canonical way to handle it.

What do you mean by "canonical"? What's your some primary criterion in mind? Is it speed, simplicity, numerical accuracy, or some other criterion? You said eigen-decomposition is unappealing. Why? You agreed that post-hoc average is the most common way. But you don't like it by which criterion? There has to be a reason for why something is the most common.

I suppose I meant in a way that is similar to how someone evaluates $A^{-1}b$ by backsolves instead of matrix inversion. Same speed, higher numerical accuracy, but the criterion is rather loose; it just has to make sense in theory and practice.

Another thought is that if double presicion floating point (fp) numerical inaccuracy truly bothers you, we can just use extended precision fp or multiple presicion fp, like gmp or mpfr.

After thinking about it for a bit, I realized there is a rather simple partial answer. For the sake of simplicity, let's rename things to:
$$
\tilde{S}=A^\intercal SA = \begin{bmatrix} \rule[0.25em]{1.25em}{0.5pt} a_1^\intercal  \rule[0.25em]{1.25em}{0.5pt} \\ \vdots \\ \rule[0.25em]{1.25em}{0.5pt} a_d^\intercal  \rule[0.25em]{1.25em}{0.5pt}\end{bmatrix}S\begin{bmatrix}  \underset{\rule[0.25em]{0.5pt}{1.3em}}{\overset{\rule{0.5pt}{1.3em}}{a_1}} & \cdots & \underset{\rule[0.25em]{0.5pt}{1.3em}}{\overset{\rule{0.5pt}{1.3em}}{a_d}}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^\intercal Sa_1 & \cdots & a_1^\intercal Sa_d\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\  a_d^\intercal Sa_1 & \cdots & a_d^\intercal Sa_d\end{bmatrix}
$$
From here, we recall that:
$$
a_i^\intercal Sa_j = \text{tr}(a_i^\intercal Sa_j)=\text{tr}(Sa_ja_i^\intercal ) \implies \tilde{S} = \begin{bmatrix} \text{tr}(Sa_1a_1^\intercal ) & \cdots & \text{tr}(Sa_1 a_d^\intercal)\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\  \text{tr}(Sa_da_1^\intercal ) & \cdots & \text{tr}(Sa_da_d^\intercal )\end{bmatrix}
$$
I think the answer is pretty obvious from this point, since multiplication is commutative, $a_ja_i^\intercal  = a_ia_j^\intercal $. This implies that we're guaranteed equality if we only evaluate the top/bottom triangle, and we evaluate:
$$
\text{tr}(Sa_ia_j^\intercal ) = \text{tr}(S (a_ia_j^\intercal) )
$$
of course, since there is no associativity, actually evaluating all of the trace terms normally can cause deviation.
Edit:
You can evaluate the trace in a symmetry preserving way by summing $S ☉ a_ia_j^\intercal$ in row major order and $S☉a_ja_i^\intercal$ in column major order.
Unfortunately, the complexity of this algorithm is quartic so we do lose some things.

Is there any reason for preferring lower triangle to upper triangle, or vice versa? If numerical inaccuracy kicks in, it may affect both. Isn't this in the same idea as post-hoc replacing lowers by uppers, or vice versa? If this is acceptable, why not average?

It's not quite the same. I implemented this in python just to try it out, and one thing you can do now is sort the elements of $\langle S,a_ia_j^\mathsf{T} \rangle$ before summing them up. This way, you're guaranteed that associativity no longer matters. However, this is just racking up the numerical FLOPS.
I think it's important to note that the scheme I sketch "feels" more like a symmetric operation than does ordinary matrix multiplication. I guess I expected there to be something a scheme someone knows about since everyone has probably encountered this. Thanks for your help!

My mind can hardly get away from averaging to ensure symmetry... If $L$ is the lower triangle matrix taken from $S$, except that the diagonals are halved, i.e., $S=L+L^T$. Then $ASA^T=ALA^T+AL^TA^T$. This is just $B=ALA^T$ added to its own transpose $B^T$, ensuring numerical symmetry.
